# How do I make this nested div to show up on top right corner and make text wrap around it?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a nested div on the top right of its parent div and text to wrap around the nested div.

I really should understand how position, float and display work together.

Here is my sample:

**CSS**

```
.parentDiv {
    width:295px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.parentDiv .childDiv1 {
    width:36px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
.parentDiv .childDiv2 {
    width:210px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
.parentDiv .childDiv3 {
    width:44px;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="childDiv1">
        <img alt="adfasf" src="../img/image.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="childDiv2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        <div class="childDiv3"> <a href="#" title="safasf" id="adasf"><span>search here</span></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Live jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/duklee/3vvcm/43/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jv6cv/)**. Make the child div appear first as a child of childDiv2 and keep the CSS as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Move it inside `.childDiv2`

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/3vvcm/44/)

CSS (no change):

```
.parentDiv {  width:295px;border:1px solid black; }
.parentDiv .childDiv1 { width:36px;border:1px solid black;float:left; }
.parentDiv .childDiv2 { width:210px;border:1px solid black;float:left; }
.parentDiv .childDiv3 { width:44px;right:0px;top:0px;border:1px solid gray; position:relative; float:right; }
​
```

HTML

```
        <div class="parentDiv">
            <div class="childDiv2">
            <div class="childDiv1">
                <img alt="adfasf" src="../img/image.gif">
            </div>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                <div class="childDiv3">
                    <a href="#" title="safasf" id="adasf"><span>search here</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>                
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version:

```
<div class="childDiv2">
    <div class="childDiv3">
        <a href="#" title="safasf" id="adasf"><span>search here</span></a>
    </div>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
```

CSS:

```
.childDiv2 { width:210px;border:1px solid black;}
.childDiv3 { width:44px;right:0px;top:0px;border:1px solid gray;float:right  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's my jsFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/3vvcm/46/)

In addition to the fix, I removed the unnecessary CSS.

The reason for this issue is parsing order. HTML is parsed left-to-right, top-to-bottom. When you have element-A declared *after* element-B, element-A will naturally be parsed *after* element-B.

As others have noted, all that needed to be done was to move the paragraph of text so that it's declared after `childDiv3`. This will allow `childDiv3` to reside on the first line of `childDiv2` and float itself normally.

Additionally, I added a margin to `childDiv1` and some padding to `parentDiv` to space things out a bit. Feel free to strip out or modify properties as you wish. I also added a `.clear` element before the closing tag of `parentDiv` so that it would properly wrap around its floated child elements, as you may have intended it to.